# Ruby, making a number negative

Tags: ruby, integer, negative-number, negative-integer

This is probably super basic, but I've tried enough things that have failed to reach out..

I want to change a number to it's negative version.

```
answer = []
array = [3, 5, 2, 19, 2, 1]

array.each.with_index do |x, i|

   if x > array[i+1]
      answer << array[i] * -1
   else x =< array[i+1]
      answer << array[i] 
   end
 end
=> the answer I want is [-5] for when 'true' but I'm getting [5]
```

I also tried making a new 'negarray' with all the equivalent negative numbers as 'array'

```
answer = []
array = [3, 5, 2, 19, 2, 1]
negarray = [-3, -5, -2, -19, -2, -1]

=> again, getting [5], and not the [-5] I want.
```

Cheers!

Comment: Cant reproduce. Getting `[-5]`.

Comment: I apologize but I do not understand this question

Comment: @ndn - Its strange as I get [5] and triple checked my code, gave it to somebody else to run and they got [-5].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the actual version the questions is unclear.

If you mean with

> I want to change a number to it's negative version.

that you want always a negative number, then you could try:

```
answer = []
array = [3, 5, 6, 19, 2, 1]

array.each do |x|
   if x > 0
      answer << x * -1
   else
      answer << x 
   end
 end

 p answer
```

or

```
array.each do |x|
   answer << if x > 0
       x * -1
   else
       x 
   end
 end
```

or with a ternary operator:

```
array.each do |x|
   answer << (x > 0 ? -x : x)
 end
```

Or shorter and more ruby-esk (using a ternary operator):

```
 array = [3, 5, 6, 19, 2, -1]
 answer = array.map { |n| n > 0 ? -n : n }
```

If you prefer the longer if:

```
 answer = array.map do |n| 
  if n > 0 
    -n 
  else
    n 
  end
 end
```

If you don't want to use any if-structure, then you could use a negative abs-method:

```
 answer = array.map { |n| -n.abs }
```

Comment: I love that negative abs method!

Answer (score 4):

WIth the following line

```
if x > array[i+1]
```

You are basically saying if the element at position `i` is greater than the position at `i+1`, you want to make it negative. The problem is that `5` is smaller than the  next element `6` and for that reason it isn't being negated.

Let's fix up your code, and use the `map` method to simplify it:

```
out = array.map.with_index do |x, i|
   (array[i+1].nil? || x > array[i+1]) ? x : x*-1
end
# [-3, -5, -6, 19, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I actually ballsed up my example there. 

I should have chose a different number to 5 to illustrate my point. Apologies. 

Thanks for your much neater solution though!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the negative value of the second array element at index 1, do the following

```
answer << array[1] * -1
```

In order to change ALL values of an array to negative numbers, use the following

```
answer = array.map { |n| -n }
```